# Adding Layout with views programmatically

Tags: android

Pretty much I have 1 main layout being a Vertical LinearLayout, at the press of a button I want to be able to add a horizontal layout with 2 edit texts. What i've done here doesn't work, no errors but nothing happens.

```
public void addView(View v){
    LinearLayout mainLayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    LinearLayout h = new LinearLayout(this);

    h.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    h.addView(new EditText(this));
    h.addView(new EditText(this));

    mainLayout.addView(h);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing that you should consider when creating a View programmatically is to set a `LayoutParams`, e.g.

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

this way you define the size of the view inside the layout, it's what you would usually set with `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes in an xml layout
in your case you should add a `LayoutParams` for the `LinearLayout` and one for each the `EditText`

Comment: oh, how did I forget that! Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, please consider upvoting and accepting if it helped. also if you have any doubts feel free to ask